# How do I create a selector with drawable and color

Tags: android, android-layout, selector, android-drawable

Here is the code I have that is presently not working. How do I get it to work? I don't want to use two files such as a shape file in addition to the selector file. Can I do this in one file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/my_col"/>

</selector>
```

I also tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/my_col" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false"><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3f68c2" />

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3f68c2" />

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out mine works. I was calling the wrong drawable into the layout file.